# How to redirect ip address using iptables

Tags: linux, redirect, iptables

I have small local network with 5 computers. My provider gave me real ip address (194.187...), but computers in the network cannot see it. So I have to make redirect on my router (with linux system), which will redirect real ip address (194.187...) to ip address which I have in provider's network (10.12.205.26).

How can I perform this with iptables on my router. Thanks.

Comment: Let me understand better. You want all the traffic pointing to your public (static) ip address will be redirected to one of the IP in your private LAN? 10.12.205.26 is the IP of one of the 5 computers?

Comment: No 10.12.205.26 is the IP of my router in provider's network

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Hope this works for you :

```
   Add (prerouting,postrouting) rules in you NAT table using

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source ip_address
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -j DNAT --to-destination ip_address

    and then use :

    iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 194.187... -j DNAT --to-destination 10.12.205.26

    iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.12.205.26 -j SNAT --to-source 194.187...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need to redirect all connections that go to 194.187... using different ports to my address 10.12.205.26, not just 8080 port