# /etc/hosts linux file pointing two address (local and internet IP)

Tags: linux, networking, ip, hosts

I have the next problem and haven't found a solution yet. I have a server (Linux debian) on a house connected to the local network with this IP 192.168.0.17. And, of course, I have a public IP (internet IP). Also I have a domain alias, for example: example.com which is pointing to my public IP so I can enter to my server from internet.

The problem is when I'm inside the house I want to write example.com and point to the local address so I can take advantage of the speed of local network. And when I'm outside the house, connected to internet, I want to write example.com and point to my local ip address.

I know that I can edit my **/etc/hosts** to do something like this

**192.168.0.17 example.com**

But what would happen when I'm outside the network? The computer will try to reach the local ip and it won't find it.

So I'm looking for something that help my computer to identify when I'm in my LAN to reach the local IP address through example.com and when I'm outside to reach my public address through example.com.

Hope someone can help me with this problem.
Cheers.

Comment: What performance problems are you seeing *exactly*? When reaching local resources through your public address you are *still* within your own LAN. Unless e.g. you have a 100Mbit router on a mostly 1Gbit LAN, going through the public address (i.e. just the router - *not* the WAN connection) would not be much of a problem is most cases...

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your public address in /etc/hosts, for example:

```
1.1.1.1 example.com
```

Then you can add an iptables rule to your router to redirect traffic targeted to 1.1.1.1 to your local desired ip. For example, you can see this:

[How to redirect ip address using iptables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14704957/how-to-redirect-ip-address-using-iptables)

Probably your router has a web interface where you can do it more user friendly.